# In C++, regarding cin and inputs, is this a bug or am I doing this wrong?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
int feet;
int inches;
cout << "How tall are you (in feet and inches)? ";
if (!(cin >> feet)) {
    cout << "Exception: Your input should only be an integer." << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (!(cin >> inches)) {
    cout << "Exception: Your input should only be an integer." << endl;
    return 0;
}

cin.clear();
cin.ignore();

double feetInCm = feet * 30.48;
double inchesInCm = ((double)inches / 12) * 30.48;
double heightInCm = feetInCm + inchesInCm;

cout << "Your height is " << heightInCm << " cm." << endl;

double input;
cin >> input;
cout << input;
```

Whenever I input something like "5 11", everything is fine, but if I input a decimal for inches, like "5 11.2", only the integer (11) in the decimal gets stored in inches and the decimal part (.2) is stored in the next double input. Also, if it matters, the code compiles as the old, default C++ (using g++), not C++11.

Edit: So I updated my code to include cin.clear() and cin.ignore(), which did not solve the problem. The decimal part (.2 from the example above) still gets sent to the next input. Also, cin still does not read the whole decimal input for inches and does not try to put it in the integer variable (which should fail and output the exception). Instead, it still stops at the dot and puts the integer in inches, while it puts the decimal in the next double input. Is there no other way around this?